# Testing Rails Controller: get and post strange behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, controller

I'm using RSpec (through the gem rspec-rails) for testing and developing
my application.
I've tried to "test" a controller and run up against a strange behavior of post and get methods (same for all the others of this kind).

In my route file:

```
controller :sessions do
    post '/login',  action: :login_create
    get  '/login',  action: :login
    get  '/logout', action: :logout
end
```

At the beginning, I was thinking that post will simulate an http post
request at the specified url, so I've wrote in my spec:

```
describe "POST 'login'" do
    it "returns http success" do
        post 'login'
        response.should be_success
        response.should render_template 'sessions/login_create'
    end
end
```

But this will call the login action, not the login_create, and then the last assert fail.
After a lot of googling and experiments, I've changed `post 'login'` with `post :login_create` and this actually works!
The strange thing is that also if I change `post` with `get`, it will continue to work! O_o
Isn't this strange? How this methods are intended to work and to be used?

In the Rails API I've not found anything else than the class: `ActionController::TestCase::Behavior`

Answer (score 1):

What you're writing is a *controller* spec, not a *request* spec. In a controller spec, routes are not consulted at all because rspec invokes controller actions directly.

When you write `post 'login'`, the `login` specifies the action name, not the URL path.

The correct way to test the `login_create` action would be to use `post :login_create` as you've discovered.

Comment: That's ok, but what is the difference between post, get, put and delete? Is it only a matter of clarity?

Comment: It sets the correct `request.method` when the action is invoked. (Sorry for the late reply!!)